The VOSK issue for Kdenlive after updating to Ubuntu 24.04
I really need VOSK installed in Ubuntu to run "speech recognition models" in Kdenlive (version 23.08.5). At the beginning I couldn't install the SRT and VOSK python modules by Kdenlive, so I had to install manually via terminal $ pip3 install srt and I got the output:
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.

    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.

    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.

    See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

I tried the command $ pip3 install vosk and I got the same output.
I saw that pip3 does NOT work anymore for Ubuntu 24.04 and above. So I had to research to find the alternative to install them, after I found, I typed the following commands to check the version of python3 and pip3, and I got the output:
$ python3 --version
Python 3.12.3

$ pip3 --version
pip 24.0 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.12)

And then I installed the SRT python module by typing the following commands:
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python3-srt

It was successful, then I tried to install the VOSK python module by typing the following commands:
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python3-vosk

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-vosk

I checked in Kdenlive that the SRT python module was installed successful but the VOSK python module is not installed yet, I tried to install VOSK by Kdenlive and it was failed.
Does anyone knows how to install that module in Ubuntu 24.04? I really need to use speech recognition in Kdenlive.
